# Where should the Page Objects be instantiated?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I would like to know where should I instantiate my Page objects?
Here is my project hierarchy:

Pages : Contains all page objects with constructor such as

```
public LoginPage extends BasePage
 {
   super(driver);
   PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

My BasePage contains all common methods such as table handling, data gathering from webtable etc..

I have a baseTest which contains all of the Page Objects instantiation and my tests are extend this class.

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
```

I have helper (non-static) classes as well for navigation, database connection, custom waits etc.

Any best practice? Basetest is the proper place to instantiate them?

Thanks!

Comment: `public LoginPage extends BasePage(WebDriver driver)` will not compile.

Comment: You are right, I made a copy paste mistake.corrected.

Comment: I strongly suggest putting the `initElements` call in the base page class.

Answer (score 1):

I instantiate page objects in the test code, but not the base class, as the scenario requires. E.g.,

```
@Test(dataProvider = PROVIDER)
public void testLogin(WebDriver driver, Info info) {
  Login login = new Login(driver);
  assertTrue(login.isDisplayed());
  login.enterCredentials(info.getUser(), info.getPw());
  Welcome welcome = new Welcome(driver);
  assertTrue(welcome.isDisplayed());
}
```

This is just one way to use page objects.

Be careful not to write too many "helper" classes, or too deep an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I use PageFactory approach which is more complex than use this in every test method. Have you had any experience in PF?

Comment: Tons of experience. The code I show here is designed to work with a page-factory approach.

Comment: I had other type of problem till now, so I would like to implement this approach what you mentioned. So If I have lots of test cases, every test case should contains the instantiation as you mentioned your example? is there any benefit against of the basePage contains all the instatiation?

Answer (score 0):

I do it in the way given below. I'm not sure how good it is. Comments and Feedback welcome.

**a.** I use an AbstractPage class which contains instantiates page objects, and also has all the object level wrapper methods such as clickButton(), sendKeys() etc. Page Object instantiation happens via constructor

```
public AbstractPage(WebDriver driverWeb) {
  this.driverWeb = driverWeb;
  PageFactory.initElements(driverWeb, this);
}
```

**b.** Then I have all my Page Classes which extend this AbstractPage -

```
public LoginCanvas(WebDriver driverWeb) {
  super(driverWeb);
}
```

**c.** Then a class which runs all my test cases. But I use cucumber so this base class just runs the cucumber scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Where do you instantiate the LoginCanvas : LoginCanvas lc = new LoginCanvas(driver);? I use cucumber as well and I have some utils/helper classes, so I have 3 packages. Helpers, PageObjects, StepDefinitions (And the resources with features files)... BasePage contains all the common custom methods (I implemented custom click, setElement etc methods with wait etc). My Basepage is like your AbstractPage, but I have baseSteps as well, where I store all page object instantiations. Is it correct?

Comment: And one more thing. I have a navigation helper class which contains all the method for navigation methods such as navigateToLogin, navigateToAboutUs etc. I cannot extend the BasePage because it is a helper class however BasePage contains all the setElement, clickElement and other common methods. I think it is a bad practice. How shall I solve it? Shall I create an ElementUtils helper class with click, set, and other basic methods? But in this case where can I instantiate it? Thanks!

Comment: I do the instantiation in step definition classes. For example, there is a section called Profile in the website. This Profile section has 3 pages. I have created 3 Page Classes for this, and 1 step definition class. Inside this step definition class I instantiate the Page Object classes

Comment: I also use 3 packages - step_definition, pages, and common. Common contains all the utilities and helper classes. For Navigation, I have 2 different types - once where when I click on some button, I'm on the same page. And the other where I navigate to a different page. For both these approaches, the navigateTo() function has similar code like this - navigateToHomePage() { clickButton(login); waitTillPageIsLoaded("Page Title");}

Comment: I don't use wrapper methods for `click` or `sendKeys` or such because those methods work just fine in the underlying library and it's a one-line cover method for one line of covered method. I prefer a style whereby a page-object method name reflects a UI function point rather than a low-level element operation. The idea of the page-object model in the first place is to hide the low-level element operations and expose functionality in UI terms. http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern hints at one approach.