# Selenium PageFactory placement in framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently I have the following classes which use PageFactory to initialize the elements that I use.

Base Class:

```
public class BaseClass {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static boolean bResult;

public BaseClass(WebDriver driver){
    BaseClass.driver = driver;
    BaseClass.bResult = true;
}}
```

Login Page Classs that holds the elements:

```
public class LoginPage extends BaseClass{

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
{
    super(driver);
}

@FindBy(how= How.XPATH, using="//input[@placeholder='Username']")
public static WebElement username;
```

Then I use a separate Login class for my actions:

```
public class Login {

//Login
public static void enterUsernamePassword(String username, String password) throws Exception{
    LoginPage.username.sendKeys(username);
    LoginPage.password.sendKeys(password);
}
```

Then my steps class:

```
 @When("^I enter a valid username (.*) and password (.*)")
public void I_enter_a_valid_username_and_password(String username, String password) throws Throwable
{
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
    Login.enterUsernamePassword(username, password);
}
```

As you can see I am using PageFactory within the steps class.  I hate doing this and would like to put the PageFactory somewhere else, just not in the steps class.

Without adding or deleting any classes, where could I place the PageFactory class?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727174/where-should-the-page-objects-be-instantiated

Comment: As you are using cucumber you can use a DI framework to manage instances, try picocontainer no code changes required and it uses constructor injection and comes out of the box with cucumber. Just add the dependency in pom. What is the purpose of having a LoginPage and Login class? Combine them into one and remove the static keyword for the webelements. Use the pagefactory code in the constructor of the pageobject.

Comment: I have removed the extra classes and placed the PageFactory into the constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best to do it is by using an Inversion Of Control / Dependency Injection framework. I use Spring but there are other options as well, e.g. [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice), [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/), [Picocontainer](http://picocontainer.com/).

Using Spring you can annotate all pages with `@Component` and add a PageObject Bean postprocessor to initialize all page elements when the pages are being created.

This approach is also recommended by the [Cucumber for Java Book](https://www.amazon.com.au/Cucumber-Java-Book-Behaviour-Driven-Development-ebook/dp/B00V20IEXM) by Aslak Hellesoy (Cucumber Ltd founder). Cucumber also provides